# Strange Request Body in Golang API

Tags: mongodb, go

I have created an API server using golang and ravel. In one of the POST methods, I need to read the body and decode it to a model before saving it. But it is failing to do so. This is the guide I used https://medium.com/@kyawmyintthein/revel-mgo-restful-generator-for-revel-web-framework-mongodb-86209de3977e

The expected behaviour is to create the user object in the mongoDB. But I am getting an error response. Something is going wrong while Decoding it to user struct.

Controller method:

```
func (c UserController) Create() revel.Result {

    fmt.Print("Body: ")
    fmt.Println(c.Request.Body)
    var (
        user models.User
        err  error
    )

    err = json.NewDecoder(c.Request.Body).Decode(&user)
    if err != nil {
        errResp := buildErrResponse(err, "403")
        c.Response.Status = 403
        return c.RenderJSON(errResp)
    }

    user, err = models.AddUser(user)
    if err != nil {
        errResp := buildErrResponse(err, "500")
        c.Response.Status = 500
        return c.RenderJSON(errResp)
    }
    c.Response.Status = 201
    return c.RenderJSON(user)
}
```

User Model:

```
package models

import (
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
    "time"
    "userAPI/app/models/mongodb"
)

type User struct {
    ID        bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    Name      string        `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    Email     string        `json:"email" bson:"email"`
    Phone     string        `json:"phone" bson:"phone"`
    Username  string        `json:"username" bson:"username"`
    CreatedAt time.Time     `json:"created_at" bson:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time     `json:"updated_at" bson:"updated_at"`
}
```

JSON body used in POST request

```
{
    "name":"kanishka",
    "email":"kanishka@gmail.com",
    "phone":"91238901238",
    "username":"k"
}
```

This is the response I am getting

```
{
    "error_code": "403",
    "error_message": "EOF"
}
```

The output of `println(c.Request.Body)` on top of the controller method shows

> &{0xc4202ffa80   false true {0 0} true false false
>   0x12a1430}

This is my first attempt at golang. Kindly help me to proceed further.

Comment: Please provide a **minimal** code example and also state your expected output. What you get as output is the standard way Go prints structs, in this case the Body.

Comment: Make sure you're not trying to read the request body twice. That doesn't work.

Comment: @Peter I'm not. I cleared out the method and tried what Cerise Limón suggested in the answer below. Still no luck :/

Comment: Your client is sending incomplete data then (maybe even nothing at all).

Comment: @Peter Please find the screenshot of the request here: https://ibb.co/jdwsFb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching, I found [this issue #1011](https://github.com/revel/revel/issues/1011). Quote to the response:

> Revel automatically calls ParseForm, ParseMultipartForm or whatever function is needed for a request, so req.Body is parsed and all valuable information is stored to controller.Params.(Fixed, Route, Query, Form, Files).

It means that, before calling your controller's method, the request body already being read by `revel`, so when you try to read it again the result will be `EOF`. From [the docs](https://revel.github.io/manual/parameters.html), instead of using `json.Decoder` and request body, try the following:

```
c.Params.BindJSON(&user)
```